# Install Hook on Joomla module

Tags: php, joomla, installation, joomla-extensions

I am trying to have an install hook run when I install a Joomla module, I have this inside my module, but it doesn't work! Do I need to call the file that this class is in some where?

```
class mod_impalawifiInstallerScript
{
/**
 * method to install the component
 *
 * @return void
 */
function install($parent)
{
```

I have looked at the Docs.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, you need to put this in your xml file.

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 1.6+, you have two options.

One, you can include a file called `install.*componentname*.php` in the root directory of your .zip file.  The file should contain one function, `com_install`.  This function will be called during the install of your component.  (More info [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_installer_API_to_support_package_installation))

The other option is to define the script to be run in your XML using the `<scriptfile>` tag.  This should be placed after the metadata, but before the file locations (alongside other install things such as SQL).  Docs and example [here.](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files)